# Convert array to nested list without nested for-loops (improved post)

Tags: r, list, for-loop, lapply

I have an array, that is imported from matlab using readMat().

The arrays have the dimensions X, 1, 1.

Each element is an other array and so on. It branches out like a nested list.

Right now every level of the array look someting like this:

```
> Array
, , 1

   [,1]                                                                   
f.name "file.EDF"                                                
CNT    List,4 

> Array[2] #This is CNT
[[1]]
, , 1

         [,1]           
FileType "EDF"          
CntGen   List,22        
CntEle   List,14        
CntEve   List,6
```

I want to convert this to a nested list, which i have done with this mess of for-loops:

```
#Removes dimensons by converting to a vector
asVec <- function(X){
    t <- lapply(X, as.vector)
    names(t) <- dimnames(X)[[1]]
    t
}

#Convert arrays to lists 
GetAna <- function(ana){
    ana<-asVec(ana)

    for(i in 1:length(ana)){ #loops through the datastructure converting one branch at a time
        if(length(dim(ana[[i]]))>1){
            ana[[i]]<-asVec(ana[[i]])   

            for(j in 1:length(ana[[i]])){
                if(length(dim(ana[[c(i,j)]]))>1){
                    ana[[c(i,j)]]<-asVec(ana[[c(i,j)]])

                    for(k in 1:length(ana[[c(i,j)]])){
                        if(length(dim(ana[[c(i,j,k)]]))>1){
                            ana[[c(i,j,k)]]<-asVec(ana[[c(i,j,k)]])
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
    ana #returns ana
}
```

This returns a list like this:

```
> list(f.name = "File.EDF", 
+        CNT = list(FileType = "EDF",
+              CntGen = list(time = "12.45.21",
+                     date = "28.01.15"),
+              ECG = "vector of ECG values"))
$f.name
[1] "File.EDF"

$CNT
$CNT$FileType
[1] "EDF"

$CNT$CntGen
$CNT$CntGen$time
[1] "12.45.21"

$CNT$CntGen$date
[1] "28.01.15"


$CNT$ECG
[1] "vector of ECG values"
```

This works, but is obviously a mess.

Are there more efficient ways to do this?

dput of data sample:

```
list(structure(list(list(structure(list(structure("ECG", .Dim = c(1L, 
1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("Accelerometer_X", .Dim = c(1L, 
1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("Accelerometer_Y", .Dim = c(1L, 
1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("Accelerometer_Z", .Dim = c(1L, 
1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("Marker", .Dim = c(1L, 
1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("HRV", .Dim = c(1L, 
1L))), .Names = "")), list(structure(list(structure("ECG electrode", .Dim = c(1L, 
1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("X-axis", .Dim = c(1L, 
1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("Y-axis", .Dim = c(1L, 
1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("Z-axis", .Dim = c(1L, 
1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("Pushbutton marker", .Dim = c(1L, 
1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("Heart Rate Variability", .Dim = c(1L, 
1L))), .Names = "")), list(structure(list(structure("uV", .Dim = c(1L, 
1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("mg", .Dim = c(1L, 
1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("mg", .Dim = c(1L, 
1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("mg", .Dim = c(1L, 
1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure(character(0), .Dim = 0:1)), .Names = ""), 
    structure(list(structure("ms", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = "")), 
    structure(c(-32768, -4045, -4017, -3877, -32768, 0), .Dim = c(1L, 
    6L)), structure(c(32767, 4045, 4017, 3877, 32767, 65535), .Dim = c(1L, 
    6L)), structure(c(-32768, -8192, -8192, -8192, -32768, -32768
    ), .Dim = c(1L, 6L)), structure(c(32767, 8192, 8192, 8192, 
    32767, 32767), .Dim = c(1L, 6L)), list(structure(list(structure(character(0), .Dim = 0:1)), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure(character(0), .Dim = 0:1)), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure(character(0), .Dim = 0:1)), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure(character(0), .Dim = 0:1)), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure(character(0), .Dim = 0:1)), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure(character(0), .Dim = 0:1)), .Names = "")), 
    structure(c(50, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1), .Dim = c(1L, 6L)), structure(c(1, 
    0.4937744140625, 0.4903564453125, 0.4732666015625, 1, 1), .Dim = c(1L, 
    6L)), structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32768), .Dim = c(1L, 6L)), 
    list(structure(list(structure("ECG", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = "")), 
    structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32768), .Dim = c(1L, 6L)), structure(c(205.8, 
    205.8, 205.8, 205.8, 205.8, 205.8), .Dim = c(6L, 1L))), .Dim = c(14L, 
1L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(c("label", "TransType", "PhysDim", 
"PhysMin", "PhysMax", "DigiMin", "DigiMax", "PreFilt", "SamplesInDataRec", 
"calib", "Offset", "readchannel", "baseline", "sens"), NULL, 
    NULL)))
```

Comment: Can you share a `dput` of some of your data?

Comment: Of cause. I have added some to the post.

Comment: Apparently drop() does the same as my asVec()